# To what value infinite sum converges to

Tags: convergence-divergence

What is the limit of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{n}{1.3.5...(2n+1)}$$

when $m \to \infty$ ?

I tried to find a recursive formula but failed to put things on place ?

Also I had a little doubt that when we say a series is converging then does we mean that terms of our series doesn't explode to infinite or sum of the series doesn't go to infinite ?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2257306/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3090048/42969

Comment: Render the term as $(1/2)[1/(1×3×5×...×(2n-1))-1/(1×3×5×...×(2n+1))]$ and telescope.

Comment: There is a specific notation for your denominators which is the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi Okay thanks I got it . Can you see My little extra doubt ?

Comment: Converging means there is a definite limit, not just the sum is bounded. The series $1-1+1-1+1-1+...$ remains bounded but can't decide between $1$ and $0$, alternating between these sums, so we call it divergent. Your series, however, really does converge. We just saw the proof.